# JPARepository and Mysql trying to get a data with every rows in a table for condition from multiple column using @Query

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I'm newbie when comes to query and i have some problems like this.

i have 2 table like this

```
transactions
+-----+------------+----------+------------+
| id  |   trans    |trans_code| trans_time |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+
|  1  |   trans1   |   x01    |   22:00    |
|  2  |   trans2   |   x01    |   17:00    |
|  3  |   trans3   |   x02    |   23:00    |
|  4  |   trans4   |   x03    |   20:00    |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+

restricted_code
+-----+--------+----------------+--------------+
| id  |  code  |time_limit_start|time_limit_end|
+-----+--------+----------------+--------------+
|  1  |  x01   |      21:00     |     24:00    |
|  2  |  x03   |      16:00     |     23:00    |
+-----+--------+----------------+--------------+

expected result
+-----+------------+----------+------------+
| id  |   trans    |trans_code| trans_time |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+
|  1  |   trans1   |   x01    |   22:00    |
|  4  |   trans4   |   x03    |   20:00    |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+
```

i want to get every transaction where the trans_code is present in any row from restricted_code table and trans_time between the time_limit_start and time_limit_end from it's respective row

i tried to use @Query in JPARepository to do the query with this code

`@Query(value = "select t from transactions t, restricted_code rc where t.trans_code = rc.code and t.trans_time >= rc.time_limit_start and t.trans_time <= rc.time_limit_end")`

is it possible to get the expected results? or i need to get all the data and loop it manually to check which transactions meet the condition?

`edit 1`
here is my code

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<TransactionRequest, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select tr.transactionAmount as transactionAmount, ta.status as transactionStatus, ta.authResponseCode as authResponseCode, tr.posEntryMode as posEntryMode, tr.serviceCode as serviceCode, ta.cardHolderName as cardHolderName, tr.transactionType as transactionType, ta.latitude as latitude, ta.longitude as longitude, b.bankName as bankName, mc.companyName as companyName, ta.txid as transactionId, ta.pan as panNumber, ta.createdDate as transactionCreatedDate from transaction_request tr, transaction_authorized  ta, bank b, merchant mc, mid m, master_mcc masmcc, unexpected_transaction_mcc utm, category_master_mcc cmmcc" +
        " where ta.transactionDate = :transactionDate " +
        " and ta.transactionTime >= :startTime " +
        " and ta.transactionTime<= :endTime " +
        " and ta.transactionAuthorizedId = tr.transactionauthorizedFk.transactionAuthorizedId " +
        " and ta.mid = m.mid" +
        " and m.bankFk = b " +
        " and m.merchantFk = mc" +
        " and mc.categoryMasterMcc = cmmcc" +
        " and cmmcc.categoryMasterMccId = masmcc.categoryMasterMccFk.categoryMasterMccId " +
        " and ((tr.serviceCode is null " +
        " and (tr.posEntryMode = '021' " +
        " or tr.posEntryMode = '022')) " +
        " or (ta.authResponseCode = '04' " +
        " or ta.authResponseCode = '07' " +
        " or ta.authResponseCode = '12' " +
        " or ta.authResponseCode = '34' " +
        " or ta.authResponseCode = '41' " +
        " or ta.authResponseCode = '43') " +
        " or ( inner join utm.mccId on masmcc.mcc and ta.transactionTime <= utm.timeLimitEnd and ta.transactionTime >= utm.timeLimitStart )) ")
    List<SuspiciousTransactionProjection> findTransactionRequestByPosEntryModeAndServiceCode(@Param("transactionDate") String transactionDate,
                                                                                             @Param("startTime") String startTime,
                                                                                             @Param("endTime") String endTime);
```

```
public interface SuspiciousTransactionProjection {
    Long getSuspiciousTransactionId();
    String getTransactionId();
    String getBankName();
    String getCompanyName();
    String getTransactionAmount();
    String getTransactionStatus();
    String getAuthResponseCode();
    String getPosEntryMode();
    String getServiceCode();
    String getCardHolderName();
    String getTransactionType();
    String getLatitude();
    String getLongitude();
    String getPanNumber();
    Date getTransactionCreatedDate();
}
```

i dont know how to make it works or cleaner
i'm pretty sure it's a mess up query

it works fine before my last query line

should i post the other entity too? since some of them have a lot of column, i don't know if this two will suffice

Comment: Replace `select t from ...` with `select t.* from ...`. The rest of the query text seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Can you Upload entities 
By using JPA repository you can get the data without using a native query also.

use this query:
select t.* from transactions t inner join restricted_code rc on t.trans_code = rc.code 
and t.trans_time >= rc.time_limit_start and t.trans_time <= rc.time_limit_end

Comment: it's a bit different from my real code, i tried to make it easier to ask since my code involve 7 tables. gimme a secs, i'll post my code